# Python "with" statement syntax

Tags: python, with-statement

I have some python code that parse the csv file. Now our vendor decide to change the data file to gzip csv file. I was wondering what's the minimal/cleanest code change I have to make. Current function:

```
def load_data(fname, cols=()):
    ... ...
    with open(fname) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        ... ...
```

I don't want to duplicate the code to load_data2(), and change the with statement to, thought it works perfectly.

```
with gzip.open(fname) as f:
```

How can I factor out the with statement?

```
def load_data(fname, cols=()):
    ... ...
    if fname.endswith('.csv.gz'):
        with gzip.open(fname) as f:
    else:
        with open(fname) as f:

        reader = csv.DictReader(f)
        ... ... # code to parse
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The universal approach is to dynamically choose an `opener`:

```
openers = {
    'http': urllib2.urlopen,
    '.csv.gz': gzip.open
    '.csv': open
}

resource_type = get_resource_type(resource) # determine the type of the resource

with openers[resource_type](resource) as f:
    # do stuff ...
```

That way, you can painlessly add more openers, when needed. Here is another example of the [factory method design pattern](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/factory_method.py).

Answer (score 8):

You can do this by assigning the function you want to use to open the file to a different variable, depending on the properties of the file name:

```
opener = gzip.open if fname.endswith('.csv.gz') else open
with opener(fname) as f:
    ... # code to parse
```

Comment: You can even do this directly in the `with` statement: `with gzip.open(fname) if fname.endswith('.csv.gz') else open(fname) as f`

Comment: Thanks, python is beautiful!